# PowerBI with Many to Many Relationship

Tags: many-to-many, powerbi, dax

I have two Tables in PowerBI with Many to Many Relationship, I need to find the exact count of the rows from both the tables (after adding filters) which are in same visualization table.

[Image showing Relationship between tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiWkJ.png)

Comment: Hi, can you outline what you have tried? and any example data, have you tried creating a measure based on COUNTROWS()

Comment: Yes I tried to created measure with Countrows, even used related Tables but I need to know how I can join the data from two tables and get the count of the final table which can also work with filters from same or other tables.

For Reference I have also included a Image in the Question